# Auto Increment Index against Unique Column Values in a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have unique values in a column, but they all have strange codes, and I want to instead have a numeric counter to identify these values. Is there a better way to do this?

```
class umm:
    inc = 0
    last_val = ''

    @classmethod
    def create_new_index(cls, new_val):
        if new_val != cls.last_val:
            cls.inc += 1
            cls.last_val = new_val
        return cls.inc

df['Doc_ID_index'] = df['Doc_ID'].apply(lambda x: umm.create_new_index(x))
```

Here is the dataframe:

```
Doc_ID  Sent_ID Doc_ID_index
0   PMC2774701  S1.1    1
1   PMC2774701  S1.2    1
2   PMC2774701  S1.3    1
3   PMC2774701  S1.4    1
4   PMC2774701  S1.5    1
... ... ... ...
46019   3469-0  3469-51 6279
46020   3528-0  3528-10 6280
46021   3942-0  3942-39 6281
46022   4384-0  4384-25 6282
46023   4622-0  4622-45 6283
```

Comment: `groupby(col).cumcount()` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method 1

```
#take the unique Doc ID's in the column
new_df=pd.DataFrame({'Doc_ID':df['Doc_ID'].unique()})
#assign a unique id 
new_df['Doc_ID_index'] = new_df.index +1
#combine with original df to get the whole df
pd.merge(df,new_df,on='Doc_ID')
```

Method 2

```
df['Doc_ID_index'] = df.groupby(['Doc_ID']).ngroup()
```

I hope this helps!